# VBA Code to split data in Range of Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have edited this question to add the code i already have.

I need a VBA Excel code to split data in Cells.

Split Rule : 
1-   Whenever you find a space " " split and put it into the next column , then
2-   Loop to the next row and do the same until Cell is blank i.e no more data.

Please refer to the attached Image for example - Data to split in Column A and the result will be in the next columns.

I tried the code below and it do the job but it doesn't loop to the next row , May you please edit this code to make it loop to next row and stop when there is no more data i.e. Blank Cell.

```
Sub example()
Dim text As String
Dim a As Integer
Dim name As Variant
text = ActiveCell.Value
name = Split(text, " ")
For a = 0 To UBound(name)
Cells(1, a + 1).Value = name(a)
Next a
End Sub
```

Thanks so much.

[image: example]

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you show us what you have already tried, people in here will be more willing to help you ;)

Comment: Thanks Victor , I added the code i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would approach this, although @Darren Bartrup-Cook's solution seems more straightforward

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim data As Range, dataList As Range
Dim arrData, i

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourWorksheetName")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set dataList = ws.Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, 1)

For Each data In dataList
    arrData = Split(data.Value)
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        ws.Cells(data.Row, i + 2).Value = arrData(i)
    Next
Next
```

**Update:** Another possibility is to use my approach in order to dynamically get the Used Range (with a couple modifications) and then replace my `For` loop with Darren's approach to perform the Split. You would end up with something like the following

```
Sub Test()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim dataList As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourWorksheetName")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set dataList = .Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, 1)
    End With

    SplitText dataList

End Sub

Sub SplitText(MyRange As Range)

    MyRange.TextToColumns Destination:=MyRange.Offset(, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
        Space:=True

End Sub
```

**Update 2:** This version will run the code for each worksheet in the workbook

```
Sub Test()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim dataList As Range

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set dataList = ws.Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, 1)
        SplitText dataList
    Next

End Sub

Sub SplitText(MyRange As Range)

    MyRange.TextToColumns Destination:=MyRange.Offset(, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
        Space:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you So Much Victor , The Code Does the Job , It do the job on the full range and it loops tell the end ,  again thank you and i am grateful

Comment: I'm glad to help. If my answer solves your problem, kindly upvote it and accept it. Thank you very much

Comment: Done , May i ask how to adjust the code to include multiple sheets within a workbook ?

Comment: You mean you want to run the code for each worksheet in your workbook?

Comment: Yes Victor exactly

Comment: Please try the **Update 2**. If you need further help I advise creating a new thread, to avoid polluting this one ;)

Answer (score 1):

The macro record shows this when using TextToColumns:

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Replacing `Selection` with your chosen range, and removing some of the parameters which have a default value of false you can use this code to split the values in the range `A2:A4`.

```
Sub Test()

    SplitText ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4")

End Sub

Sub SplitText(MyRange As Range)

    MyRange.TextToColumns Destination:=MyRange.Offset(, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
        Space:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Darren this one do the job , thank you so much for your effort and time

Answer (score 0):

I have just made a quick and dirty example. It only matches your example and has to be expanded to match several cases.

```
Public Sub spliting()

Dim row As Integer
Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")
row = 1
Dim TestArray As Variant
With ws
    Do
        TestArray = split(CStr(.Cells(row, 1).Value))
        .Cells(row, 2) = TestArray(0)
        .Cells(row, 3) = TestArray(1)
        .Cells(row, 4) = TestArray(2)
        row = row + 1
    Loop Until row = 4
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks RhyminSimon